# Variable Data binding Angular

Tags: angular, select, binding, ngfor

¿Cómo puedo sacar el valor seleccionado {{coche.id}} a una variable externa para poder usarlo después como indice aquí [routerLink]="['/detalles',seleccionFinal2[0]?

```
 <select class="mt-2"  [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado2"  (change)="capturarId()">
                    <option></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let coche of seleccionFinal">
                        <p>{{coche.modelo+' ('+coche.anio+')'}}</p>
                       <p>{{coche.id}}</p>

                    </option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <input
                    class="btn h3 boton waves-effect waves-light mt-5 mb-2"
                    type="submit"
                    value="Mostrar"
                    [routerLink]="['/detalles',seleccionFinal2[0]]"

                >
```

Comment: Es un sitio en español no es necesaria tu traduccion al ingles

Comment: Cre que debes subir la parte del input dentro de la iteracion para asi usar correctamente el id

Comment: El botón no puede ir dentro del select hombre, gracias por comentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignar valor a la opción y cuando cambies la opción del `select` gracias al doble binding tendrás el valor del `coche.id` en `opcionSeleccionado2` y puedes añadir esta variable en el `routerLink`

```
<select class="mt-2" [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado2" (change)="capturarId()">
    <option></option>
    <option *ngFor="let coche of seleccionFinal" [value]="coche.id">
        <p>{{coche.modelo+' ('+coche.anio+')'}}</p>
        <p>{{coche.id}}</p>

    </option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
 <input 
        class="btn h3 boton waves-effect waves-light mt-5 mb-2" 
        type="submit" 
        value="Mostrar" 
        [routerLink]="['/detalles',opcionSeleccionado2]"
  />
```

Comment: Si señor!!! 
Muchísimas Gracias!!!

Comment: @JaimeGómezCabezas encantado de haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas `routerLink`, el funcionamiento es el siguiente:

1. Creas un enlace en tu plantilla. En tu caso con

   ```
   [routerLink]="['/detalles',seleccionFinal2[0]]"
   ```

   Esto crea una dirección del tipo `/detalles/<valor_selección>`.
2. En el router declaras algo como

   ```
   { path: 'detalles/:valor', component: DetallesComponent },
   ```
3. En el componente que tiene que recibir ese valor (en mi ejemplo `DetallesComponent`), usas el router para obtener ese valor:

   ```
     constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, ...) {
       this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
           this.valor = params.get('valor');
       });
     }
   ```

Y obtendrás el valor que se haya pasado en la URL